# How to make Dynamic text box push other controls down

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, textfield

This is a really easy one that I thought would be easily found on google but I can't think of the terminology.

I'm using CS4 and AS3 with a few multi-line dynamic text boxes beneath one another. When I populate the top text box I would like it to automatically push down the other text boxes beneath it when the content flows on to extra lines.

At the moment it only wraps to the gap that is between each text box but then stops when reaching the text box beneath.

Is there a property to allow for this (I've worked in Silverlight and there was on controls there) that I can just set or will I have to manually implement this and call functionality to re-set all the controls y properties each time I change the text in the text box?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you really need to be working in Flex.

Comment: Even for such simplistic functionality? Surely it must be built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need the textfield to be autosized

```
myTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT
```

then you need to listen to the textfield changes, or the user typing in it

```
myTextField.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, function(e:Event):void{
    var newHeight:number = myTextField.height;
}
```

based on the new height you can move the other elements under it up or down

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any property to easily do this, but I have manually implemented something similar. Whenever you want to adjust your textFields call a function similar to this:
(untested code)

```
 private function arrangeText():void {

    var maxWidth:Number = 400; //the ending width of your

    //Set width to something low for all textfields, 
    //to get accurate reading of textWidth
    txtTitle.width = 200; 
    txtSub.width = 200;

    //Set autosizing temporarily
    txtTitle.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    txtSub.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

    //Get roughly the number of lines required to display all the text
    var titleLines:Number = Math.ceil(txtTitle.textWidth / maxWidth) - 1;
    var subLines:Number = Math.ceil(txtSub.textWidth / maxWidth) - 1;

    //Now that you know roughtly how many lines are needed, 
    //Take off autosizing
    txtTitle.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.NONE;
    txtSub.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.NONE;

    //set textfield widths bask to normal
    txtTitle.width = maxWidth;
    txtSub.width = maxWidth;

    //Apply new height values to textfields
    //Prevent textfields from being too tall as well with the "> 3" part
    txtTitle.height = (titleLines > 3 ? 100 : txtTitle.textHeight) + 5;
    txtSub.height = (subLines > 3 ? 60 : txtSub.textHeight) + 5;

    //Starting from the top going down
    //Move each of your textfields under the previous one
    txtSub.y = txtTitle.x + txtTitle.height;

}
```

Comment: You highlight that 'we now know roughly how many lines there will be', yet you randomly set your text boxes widths to 200 (half the full width). I don't think roughly correct would suffice for a top end product for a client. Why is there a random check for 3 lines too? What's so special about there being more than 3 lines? Also the magic 100, 60 and 5, what do they represent?

Comment: Good questions let me explain. If you read through the code again, the 200 width is a temporary state that is immediately adjusted by the ".autoSize" property. You should be able to set it to 400 or less with the same result. By the time you calculate the lines you are using the actual text width as determined by ".autoSize". The 3 lines was just a way to control the layout, if it ended up being say 50 lines then that would completely ruin the layout, so some sort of limit should be in place. The other values should be calculated from your textFields heights/font sizes. The 5 is extra padding.

Comment: Aah OK, I get you. I couldn't get my head round it because I'm using a scroll bar so my mind was in a different context! Thanks for the declaration.